# Extending/modifying proxy functionality (concerning the cookie header)?

Tags: proxy, nginx, squid, cookies

a few months ago I wrote a proxy in python that modifies certain request. It added a cookie header towards the requested webpage and removed that header on the way back. However I lost this code due to a hard drive failure and data recovery is pretty much out of the picture.
Now I am thinking to rewrite the whole thing as a plugin for Squid or Nginx or other proxy servers. Is there a proxy software that provides the possibility to pass on requests to a plugin or programme that modifies the data which the server picks up and acts as told by the programme.
Basically I am looking for a proxy that provides the option to customize cookie handling. Of course I am not looking for the complete solution but I would be happy if someone could point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

ok I think after hours of googeling I found what I was looking for
http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ContentAdaptation